# Bootstrap3 row getting pushed to two lines

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is not exactly how my code is but for the sake of an example, I have a 3 column layout, first column being a `col-md-3`, and inside that I have 3 more columns, one which is `col-md-1`.  However, because `col-md-1` has a width of less than the padding (30px), the column to its right is now pushed to the second line.

to see my example, pull the divider until you are in desktop mode, and notice how the blue column is now on a separate line:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pQyjbrd7v4dWN4Ffkq9b?p=preview

Does this mean I can't have a column that small?  I am coming from Bootstrap 2.x where the span1 had a width with a margin-left, so it used to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "Correct, can't have a column that small."  You can't have a "1" sized column within a "3" side column for your purpose. The math is that the tiny column you're trying to display is only 2% (i.e., 8.3% of 25%) of the available page layout. On top of the Bootstrap 3 cols have a 15px left and right padding, which effectively wipes out that 2%.  This is why you're seeing it wrap funny at anything less than about 1410 pixels, by my testing with your code. I don't know what you're trying to do, but the grid probably isn't the right way to do it for a so small a slice of the page.